Quartile Coefficient of Variation: Q1+Q3 versus Median
A common measure for the dispersion of a probability distribution is the coefficient of variation ($CV$), calculated as $$CV = \frac{\sigma}{\mu}$$.
However, for some types of distributions it may not be appropriate, and in the literature I can find other measures based on the quartiles of the distribution. There are however two ways to calculate "quartile based coefficient of variation" / "quartile coefficient of dispersion" / "quartile coefficient of variation" / "coefficient of quartile variation" (there is just no consistent naming for these):
$$CV_Q = \frac{Q_3 - Q_1}{Q_3 + Q_1}$$
or
$$CV_Q = \frac{Q_3 - Q_1}{Q_2}$$
The latter variant seems to be used primarily in elastography, for example in the measurement of liver stiffness by ultrasound (1), while the former variant seems to be more common in the major parts of literature, and was apparently introduced in this book (That may however not be the primary source... Possibly it is way older than 1999): CRC Standard Probability and Statistics Tables and Formulae (1999) by Zwillinger and Kokoska on page 17.
So far, I could not find any description whenever both variants have similar or different meaning and why one should be preferred over the other. For the latter variant, there is a comment in another question here: Coefficient of Variation with Population Median

This is a different measure. It's not, in general, a good estimator of SD/mean. For skewed data, the median isn't usually a good estimator of the mean and the IQR isn't expected to equal the SD.

Thus, always the former variant should be preferred when working with skewed distributions?

CV's generally, and these CV's in particular, do not measure anything about dispersion: they are indicators of the shape of the distribution.

@whuber okay, interesting - I always used them in that way, however they were never mentioned in the statistics courses I had and thus I might just use them in a wrong way (or have a wrong understanding of the term "dispersion"). Looks like that also the corresponding wikipedia article needs an update then :D https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_dispersion

I see what you mean.  It's a good thing that article has a huge disclaimer at the beginning concerning its possible lack of reliability!

Yes, I saw that too. However, I had a quick look into recent textbooks (for example Boslaugh S. "Statistics in a nutshell, 2nd ed." (2012)) which states that measures of dispersion are sometimes called measures of variability, and that CV is such a measure. I checked other books our library has available online, but most of them do not mention CV at all.

Found also a very old source, which mentions that CV is a measure of dispersion: https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.57860/page/n57/mode/1up

It comes down to what you mean by "dispersion" or "variability."  Those who nominate the CV as such a measure necessarily take a broad view of what "variability" is.  I do not dispute the validity of such a perspective, but I also believe it loses some useful distinctions.

The statement you have quoted is surely correct, but I'm not sure your final statement follows from it.
Indeed, one reason for choosing the median over the mean in skewed distributions is that it is different. If you want the regular CV, you can always use it (although there are other problems besides skewed distributions). Why try to get close to something that you can get precisely?
Barring reasons not to do so, I would use the first one, if only because it is commonly used and will cause less confusion. If you want to show more detail, fine - you can use a five- or seven-number summary, or a density plot, or a quantile normal plot, etc.

I have a particular example, where I look at "strain energy density" distributions. These are always positive values and the distributions are usually quite skewed and long tailed. I used a Gamma distribution for approximation and calculated CV from it. However, it is very sensitive. Thus, using the quartile based approach seemed like a good idea. But then I found there are several implementations for apparently the same thing...
